# php - multiple connections to database

Tags: php, connection

I have a login page that gets the username and pwd and sanitises them before passing them to DB.

this is done through a function:

```
function make_safe($text) {
  open_db_connection(); //this opens another connection!

  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $text = stripslashes($text);
  }
  $text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
  return $text;
}
```

this function is called from a script that already has an open connection, but still, I found that I have to open another connection INSIDE ´make___safe()´ to make it work (otherwise I get a "Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user blablabla@localhost ..."

I was wondering:

1) when I call make_safe, I already have an open connection - why is it not enough??

2) what are the problems in opening multiple connections?

thanks,
patrick

Comment: I'm not an expertin php but `make_safe` has nothing to do with the occurance of multiple connections to the DB, does it?

Comment: o.k.w.: mysql_real_escape_string() needs a connection to operate.  By default, it uses the most recently opened connection.  So, yes, multiple connections being open could have an effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to supply the second argument to mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: The second parameter is the ( resource $linkIdentifier ) by default it will use the last open connection, but you could specify an older connection.